# Jenkins Job to check failed job within 24 hours

Tags: jenkins, groovy

This script gives me all Jenkins failed jobs. However, I am trying to see failed jobs from last 24 hours only. Is there a way i can get failed job based on time?

```
    def jobBuilds=it.getLastFailedBuild()
    jobBuilds.each { build ->
      def currentStatus = build.buildStatusSummary.message
      if (currentStatus.contains("broken")) {
        println "Build: ${build} | Status: ${currentStatus}"
      }
    }
  }

**My Jenkins Console output**

Last Failed Job and Build: 24-hours-job-status #20 | Status : broken since build #18
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: analyze #29 | Status : broken since build #28
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: build-status #11 | Status : broken since this build
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: git-hub-project #4 | Status : broken since this build
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: job1 #2 | Status : broken since this build
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: job2 #2 | Status : broken since this build
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: job3 #2 | Status : broken for a long time
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: job4 #6 | Status : broken since build #3
[Pipeline] echo
Last Failed Job and Build: success-failed-job #54 | Status : broken since build #53
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution similar to the following should inspire you

```
import hudson.model.Job
import hudson.model.Result
import hudson.model.Run
import java.util.Calendar
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

//24 hours in a day, 3600 seconds in 1 hour, 1000 milliseconds in 1 second
long time_in_millis = 24*3600*1000
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).findAll { Job job ->
    !job.isBuilding()
}.collect { Job job ->
    //find all matching items and return a list but if null then return an empty list
    job.builds.findAll { Run run ->
        job.lastBuild.result == Result.FAILURE && ((rightNow.getTimeInMillis() - run.getStartTimeInMillis()) <= time_in_millis)
    } ?: []
}.sum().each{ job -> 
  println "${job}" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! When i run this script i get this, It doesn't do anything, Am i missing anything? Thank you for your help.


Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: I'm running this script with success from the script console in jenkins. Maybe do the same and try to tweak some of the expressions / conditions in the script to see if it's a problem with your setup/data or with script itself ? Note that in my script I'm not printing anything because I run it in script console. Feel free to adapt it

Comment: @janasu I've updated my answer to add println statement so it should work also in your case (out of /script context)

Comment: Thanks @MorganGeek. Updated scripts prints this. However, I wanted to print the list of failed job with in 24 hours.
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
List-of-failed-job #6
[Pipeline] echo
List-of-failed-job #5
[Pipeline] echo
List-of-failed-job #4
[Pipeline] echo
List-of-failed-job #3
[Pipeline] echo
List-of-failed-job #2
[Pipeline] echo
List-of-failed-job #1
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Well you should have exactly that with the script. Not sure what is missing for your case. Would need more info in order to help.

Comment: For some reason it only shows multibranch pipelines, but not regular pipelines, any idea why?

Comment: @MorganGeek This is a great solution. However, if a job failed 3 times, it shows all 3 fails. Is it possible to only show the most recent?